# Pandas Merge - How to avoid duplicating columns but not identical. I am trying to merge about 12 datasets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge 12 different datasets of various stocks into a single datasets based on the "Date" column.

I used the following code

```
**datasets = [amer_air,alsk_air,hwi_air,cred_sui,deut_bk,gld_schs,bsh_hc,jnj,mrk,apple,amazon,google]**

**import functools
from functools import reduce

stk_prc = functools.reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on="Date"), datasets)**


Though the merge was successful, the column names were getting repeated with suffix _x and _y.

**Index(['Date', 'Close_x', 'Close_y', 'Close_x', 'Close_y', 'Close_x',
       'Close_y', 'Close_x', 'Close_y', 'Close_x', 'Close_y', 'Close_x',
       'Close_y'],
      dtype='object')**
```

Since this is the initial steps of data preparation, am unable to proceed further. Tried other answers but unable to find a solution or the most of the solution specifies merging 2 datasets.

Comment: could you please show your code and the expected output, output you are getting

Comment: @manjari this is the output that am getting. Each dataset has got 6 columns with the names Open, High, Low, Close, Adj. close and Volume. So along with the date there are 73 columns. After the merge, the following output is what I get.




Date Open_x High_x Low_x Close_x Adj Close_x Volume_x Open_y High_y Low_y ... Low_x Close_x Adj Close_x Volume_x Open_y High_y Low_y Close_y Adj Close_y Volume_y
0 01-10-2010 9.29 9.39 9.21 9.29 8.758067 3603800 12.932500 12.962500 12.367500 ... 152.199997 153.710007 153.710007 8683400.0 264.010437 264.319275 260.523499 261.828613 261.828613 4466600.0

Comment: @SriramK Add your data to the post by editing it.

Comment: could you please provide your sample datasets

Comment: Date Open          High Low                 Close Adj Close Volume
01/10/10 10.219643 10.235 10.048214 10.09 8.719163       448142800


This is how each the sample datasets are.

Comment: It is not clear, please specify: Is each dataset made of only one stcok ? do you want to have all stocks in only one dataset sorted by date ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact that all your DataFrames contain the same information (column names) just for different stocks. Additionally, I do not think that not having the "_x" and "_y" suffixes would solve your problem as you still have to be able to differentiate the stocks in the merged DataFrame.

Depending on the way you want to analyse this data later on, I see two useful ways to combine the DataFrames.

### Input:

```
amer_air = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['Date', 'Open', 'Close', 'Low', 'High'],
    data=[
        ['2019-09-01', 10, 11, 9, 12],
        ['2019-09-02', 11, 10, 8, 11],
        ['2019-09-03', 10, 11, 9, 12]
    ]
)
alsk_air = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['Date', 'Open', 'Close', 'Low', 'High'],
    data=[
        ['2019-09-01', 7, 11, 5, 12],
        ['2019-09-02', 11, 6, 8, 11],
        ['2019-09-03', 6, 11, 9, 12]
    ]
)
hwi_air = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['Date', 'Open', 'Close', 'Low', 'High'],
    data=[
        ['2019-09-01', 10, 11, 9, 12],
        ['2019-09-02', 11, 10, 8, 11],
        ['2019-09-03', 10, 11, 9, 12]
    ]
)

# Put all DataFrames in a dictionary with stock name to make iterations easier
dfs = {
    'amer_air': amer_air,
    'alsk_air': alsk_air,
    'hwi_air': hwi_air,
}
```

### Solutions:

#### First Solution:

Instead of merging the DataFrames they can be concatenated so that we have on row per combination of date and stock.

Code:

```
# add names of stocks to DataFrames
dfs_tmp = {}
for stock, df in dfs.items():
    df['stock_name'] = stock
    dfs_tmp[stock] = df
dfs = dfs_tmp
del dfs_tmp

# combine individual DataFrames
df_out = pd.concat(dfs.values(), ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
         Date  Open  Close  Low  High stock_name
0  2019-09-01    10     11    9    12   amer_air
1  2019-09-02    11     10    8    11   amer_air
2  2019-09-03    10     11    9    12   amer_air
3  2019-09-01     7     11    5    12   alsk_air
4  2019-09-02    11      6    8    11   alsk_air
5  2019-09-03     6     11    9    12   alsk_air
6  2019-09-01    10     11    9    12    hwi_air
7  2019-09-02    11     10    8    11    hwi_air
8  2019-09-03    10     11    9    12    hwi_air
```

#### Second Solution:

Identify the different stocks through a MultiIndex and merge the DataFrames:

Code:

```
dfs_tmp = {}
for stock, df in dfs.items():
    df = df.set_index('Date')
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[stock], df.columns])
    dfs_tmp[stock] = df
dfs = dfs_tmp
del dfs_tmp
df_out = reduce(
    lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, right_index=True, left_index=True),
    dfs.values()
)
```

Output:

```
           amer_air                alsk_air                hwi_air               
               Open Close Low High     Open Close Low High    Open Close Low High
Date                                                                             
2019-09-01       10    11   9   12        7    11   5   12      10    11   9   12
2019-09-02       11    10   8   11       11     6   8   11      11    10   8   11
2019-09-03       10    11   9   12        6    11   9   12      10    11   9   12
```

Comment: Great answer. I think the second solution can also be done with `pd.concat(dfs.items(), axis=1, keys=dfs.keys())`?  (With some accounting for date as index)

Comment: It can also be done with concat, that's right. However, it would need to be `df_out = pd.concat(dfs.values(), axis=1, keys=dfs.keys())` and I could remove the line to set the MultiIndex. Do you see any reason why one approach would be better than the other? Also concat would always be equivalent to outer merge, where merge can be inner or outer.

Comment: Oh right, my mistake on items vs values. I think that in my mind concat is an easier and less imperative way to do the same thing. Also, concat has a `join='inner'` option. It's possible to read concat as just another kind of merge.

Comment: Hi @vogelstein I looked at both the solutions and found the second one more suitable. So tried the same with the following code after creating the dictionary as suggested. But it is throwing an error.


**dfs_tmp = {}
for stock, df in dfs.items():
    df = df.set_index('Date')
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[stock], df.columns])
    dfs_tmp[stock] = df
dfs = dfs_tmp
del dfs_tmp
df_out = reduce(
         lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, right_index=True, left_index=True), dfs.values())**


AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: It seems that the dictionary was not created correctly, more specifically, what is supposed to be DataFrames in the dictionary are Series instead. Would you mind sharing your code for creating the dictionary? Also, could it be that for at least one of the stocks, the original DataFrame is not correct?

Comment: **dfs = {'amer_air':amer_air, 'alsk_air':alsk_air, 'hwi_air':hwi_air, 'cred_sui':cred_sui, 'deut_bk':deut_bk, 'gld_schs': gld_schs, 'bsh_hc':bsh_hc, 'jnj':jnj, 'mrk':mrk, 'apple':apple, 'amazon':amazon, 'google':google}**


The code that was used to create the dictionary @vogelstein.

As you said, I'll also have a look at each DataFrame if they are right.

Comment: Then I guess that at least one of the supposed DataFrames is not acutally a DataFrame, but instead a Series.

Comment: That's great :), if you are happy please accept and upvote

Answer (score 0):

you should use the suffixes parameter to set each column its own suffix:

```
datasets = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
suffix = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4']

stk_prc = df1
for i, df in enumerate(datasets[1:]):
    stk_prc = pd.merge(stk_prc, df, on="Date", suffixes=(f'_{suffix[i]}', f'_{suffix[i + 1]}'))

Date   Open_df1   High_df1    Low_df1   Close_df1   Adj Close_df1   Volume_df1   Open_df2   High_df2    Low_df2   Close_df2   Adj Close_df2   Volume_df2   Open_df3   High_df3    Low_df3   Close_df3   Adj Close_df3   Volume_df3   Open_df4   High_df4    Low_df4   Close_df4   Adj Close_df4   Volume_df4
0  01/10/10  10.219643     10.235  10.048214       10.09        8.719163    448142800  10.219643     10.235  10.048214       10.09        8.719163    448142800  10.219643     10.235  10.048214       10.09        8.719163    448142800  10.219643     10.235  10.048214       10.09        8.719163    448142800
```